# not a single-group group function when using max

Tags: oracle

I am trying to get out the max `avrg` using query below but I am getting wrror saying

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
>   00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 1 Column:

```
SELECT B.STUDENT_ID,
       A.FRIST_NAME,
       A.FATHER_NAME,
       A.LAST_NAME,
       SUM (B.GRADE) AS SUM_GRADE,
       COUNT(B.COURSE_ID) AS COURSE_COUNT,
       max(SUM(B.GRADE) / COUNT(B.COURSE_ID)) AS AVRG
  FROM STUDENT A,
       STUDENT_COURSE B
  WHERE A.STUDENT_ID = B.STUDENT_ID
GROUP BY A.FRIST_NAME, A.FATHER_NAME, A.LAST_NAME, B.STUDENT_ID;
```

this error gone when I remove the `max` function any one can help me why ?
I tried to use having `max`but I am getting error that says invalid renational

any way to use having with this query ?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use your current query (without `MAX`) as an inline view, and apply the `MAX` function to "sum/count":

```
SELECT student_id,
       first_name,
       father_name,
       last_name,
       sum_grade,
       course_count,
       -- this:
       MAX(avrg) max_avrt
FROM (-- your current query 
       SELECT b.student_id,
              a.frist_name,
              a.father_name,
              a.last_name,
              SUM(b.grade) AS sum_grade,
              COUNT(b.course_id) AS course_count,
              SUM(b.grade) / COUNT(b.course_id) AS avrg
       FROM student a,
            student_course b
       WHERE a.student_id = b.student_id
       GROUP BY a.frist_name,
                a.father_name,
                a.last_name,
                b.student_id
     )
GROUP BY student_id, first_name, father_name, last_name, sum_grade, course_count;
```

However, you won't achieve anything *good*, as you'd still get the same record set due to outer `GROUP BY` clause. Consider using `SUM` in its **analytic** form.

Here's a simple example which shows what I mean, based on Scott's schema.

This is what you have now:

```
SQL> select deptno, sum(sal) / count(*) ssc
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno
  4  order by deptno;

    DEPTNO        SSC
---------- ----------
        10 2916,66667
        20 2258,33333
        30 1566,66667
```

Apparently, you'd like to select the first SSC value (2916). If you apply what I wrote earlier (i.e. use that query as an inline view), you'd get this:

```
SQL> select deptno, max(ssc) max_ssc
  2  from (select deptno, sum(sal) / count(*) ssc
  3        from emp
  4        group by deptno
  5       )
  6  group by deptno
  7  order by deptno;

    DEPTNO    MAX_SSC
---------- ----------
        10 2916,66667
        20 2258,33333
        30 1566,66667

SQL>
```

No improvement, eh? So, **analytical function** might be what you need:

```
SQL> select deptno,
  2         max(sum(sal) / count(*)) over (order by deptno) max_ssc
  3  from emp
  4  group by deptno
  5  order by deptno;

    DEPTNO    MAX_SSC
---------- ----------
        10 2916,66667
        20 2916,66667
        30 2916,66667
```

This does return desired MAX value (if that's what you're looking for. If not, explain what you'd want to get as a result).

Comment: Please, edit your initial message and provide a test case. I showed you - using sample Scott's schema - that it *works*, so I'd have to see why it doesn't work for you.